# Why images are not randomizing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, viewdidload

I would like one of two images, `apple sauce.jpg` and `8292.jpg` to appear when the app is first opened. However, I have opened the app several times and `8292.jpg` always appears. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

int randomimages = rand() % 2;

switch (randomimages) {
    case 0:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple sauce.jpg"];
        break;
    case 1:
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"8292.jpg"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

theLabel.text = @"Submit it!";

   [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not seed your random number generator:

```
$ man 3 rand
```

> [...] If no seed value is provided, the functions are automatically seeded with a value of 1.

Fix is easy: Insert this somewhere in your app startup process, for example in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

```
sranddev();
```

Comment: So does that go in the `.h` file? Also, do I need to insert the `$ man 3 rand`?

Comment: No, that's how to read documentation on `rand` in the Terminal. And the `sranddev();` line goes into any function or method that is being called before you need `rand()`. For example in the app's startup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running your code, `rand()` method always return `16807`. I don't know. But, I try this code, `rand()` work normal

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
    int randomNum = rand();
    NSLog(@"randomNum=%d, result=%d", randomNum, randomNum % 2);
}
```

Edited:

Add this code `srand(time(NULL))` before `rand()` method. It will work.